# Creating a lookup on Parent object's field

Tags: lookup

Can we create a lookup on one of the Parent object's field i.e create lookup on Child Object (Field B) to Parent object's field (Field A) such that at the time of record creation, Field B gives the lookup for Parent object's Field A. 
For eg:
Parent Object (Account)
Field - Phone (12345, 45678, 10120)

Child Object (Contact)
Field- Contact Phone- 
Available values should be 12345, 45678, 10120

Comment: Can you explain better ? it seems a bit confusing what you'd like to have.

Comment: I've updated my question. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

So, you want to be able to select in a lookup field a value from a parent object other that the name. That won't be possible using out-out-the box functionality,  you can only lookup by the name of the parent object. However, if what you want is to retrieve the value from the parent object into the child object, you could do it automatically using a formula or a workflow rule, so that every time a contact is created the fields in the contact object will be populated with the values in the parent object.

If you really need to implement a lookup type of functionality to select an option between different values on the parent object you would need to create custom code.